# Transforming dataset to aggregate values

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this below

```
Col  Value
  A      1
  A      0
  A      1
  A      1
  A      1
  B      0
  B      1
  B      0
  B      1
  B      1
```

How do I transform this so that it looks like this below

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
   A     4     1
   B     3     2
```

`Col2` counts all the 1s and `Col3` counts all the 0s for each factor value in `Col1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or we can use `dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df1, Col~Value, value.var='Value', length)
```

Answer (score 2):

For this, you can just use `table`:

```
table(mydf)
##    Value
## Col 0 1
##   A 1 4
##   B 2 3
```

---

Or:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mydf)[, as.list(table(Value)), by = Col]
##    Col 0 1
## 1:   A 1 4
## 2:   B 2 3
```

Comment: i did that but when i store this as a dataframe, `df=as.data.frame(table(mydf))`, i see just two columns,

Comment: @ErnestPresley - try `as.data.frame.matrix(...)`

Comment: @ErnestPresley YAXYP (Yet Another [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: @thelatemail, col1 turns into rownames when i do as.data.frame.matrix

Comment: @ErnestPresley, try `library(data.table); as.data.table(mydf)[, as.list(table(Value)), by = Col]`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, `Error in `[.data.table`(as.data.table(mydf), , as.list(table(Value)),  :   j doesn't evaluate to the same number of columns for each group`

Comment: @ErnestPresley, do you have values other than 0 and 1?

Comment: @AnandaMahto, no, only 1 and 0

Answer (score 0):

Another approach of aggregating the values is:

```
df <- data.frame(Col=c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"), Value=c(1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1))

new_df <- as.data.frame(with(df, tapply(Value, list(Col, Value), FUN = function(x) length(x))))

new_df <- setNames(cbind(rownames(new_df), new_df), c("Col1","Col2","Col3"))

new_df 

     Col1 Col2 Col3
 A    A    1    4
 B    B    2    3
```

We can set rownames to NULL if do not wish to see them:

```
rownames(new_df) <- NULL
```

Result:

```
   Col1 Col2 Col3
1    A    1    4
2    B    2    3
```